# Error with application.ontime method in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I havew live data feed in excel, now want to record data as shown here:

[image]]

I wrote on code as follows

```
Option Explicit

Dim SchedRecalc As Date
Sub Recalc()
    Range("A1").Value = Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy")
    Range("B1").Value = Format(Time, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")

    Call SetTime
End Sub

Sub SetTime()
    SchedRecalc = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime SchedRecalc, "Recalc"
    Application.OnTime SchedRecalc, "Record"

End Sub

Sub Record()
'
' update Macro
'


    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Sheet1.Range("A1:A169").Copy _
        Destination:=mySheet.Range("E9")
        Sheet1.Range("E9:E169").Insert Shift:=xlShiftToRight

        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End With

End Sub


Sub Disable()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=SchedRecalc, Procedure:="Recalc",                
    Schedule:=False
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=SchedRecalc, Procedure:="Record",    
    Schedule:=False

End Sub
```

but following error is coming.. i have disabled all security setting:

[image]]

Comment: Where is the `Record` macro? It should be in a normal module and that module should not also be called `Record`.

Comment: Yes it was not in normal modual .. it works

Comment: There is one error or i dont know... how to restrict the this code to one sheet only... while running code i switch the sheets , code runs in current sheet opened.

Comment: Qualify all ranges with a specific worksheet.

Comment: yes i did ...but if i switch the sheet ...error with method comes... is there any to run the code in background also if i switch the sheets or open another workbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully ran your code. Make sure the procedure you reference using Application.OnTime is placed into a **Module**.

You may also double check your last line. Copying and pasting your code didn't make the VBA editor happy.

```
Sub Disable()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=SchedRecalc, Procedure:="Recalc",                
    Schedule:=False
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=SchedRecalc, Procedure:="Record",    
    Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

It should be on one line.

```
Sub Disable()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=SchedRecalc, Procedure:="Recalc", Schedule:=False
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=SchedRecalc, Procedure:="Record", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello All, I am running workbook as running for two day.. the sheet is seemed to work slow. Is there any edits that can faster sheets to calculate.

Comment: You have a lot of movement happening in the cells. If you can live without seeing what's going on while the program is running, you could try adding a `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning as well as an `Applcation.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end. Otherwise, you might re-evaluate the copy/paste procedure and make it something else.